# Secure an entire website with a simple login for certain users

Tags: .htaccess, security, web-hosting

I have a staging and development environment. This environment hosts all kinds of things: html's, Wordpress installations, ... These two environments should be protected with a login from all external traffic. I created a .htaccess file and a .htpasswd file to define users that can login on these environments.

This method isn't ideal when developping a web application online, you have to authenticate on all devices and browsers.

I now want to create a situation where I can give permanent access without authentication to certain users within our network.

**1) Allow certain IP adresses in .htaccess**

This is not an option. All traffic goes through our firewall. This makes that every client uses the same IP. I can't add this IP as an exception because everyone in our network would be able to access all environments.

**2) MAC address filter**

After research I found out that this doesn't seem to be an option, as MAC addresses aren't sent in HTTP headers. Is this correct?

Is there any other way you can think of, on how I can achieve this setup?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to do it without authentication, unless there's some other (non-spoofable) feature of their network/config.

It might be simple to use a client side certificate to authenticate your users?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_howto.html

Then you can just distribute a certificate to all of your trusted users and they can use that to authenticate themselves.

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet so I don't think there's a way to do it the way I wanted :) I will look into the SSL certificates to see if this can be the solution for my problem. Thanks for your help.